# OAuth problem using linkedin ruby gem

Tags: ruby, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to connect to the linkedin API using the linkedin gem. I have the following code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "yaml"
require "linkedin"

config = YAML.load_file("config.yml")

client = LinkedIn::Client.new(config["linkedin"]["consumer_key"], config["linkedin"]["consumer_secret"])
rtoken = client.request_token.token
rsecret = client.request_token.secret

puts client.request_token.authorize_url

puts "Access this URL get the PIN and paste it here:"
pin = gets

puts client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)
```

When I run this code, every OAuth step works fine, except for the last one (`authorize_from_request`). It gives the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.4/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:181:in `request': additional_authorization_required (OAuth::Problem)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.4/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:197:in `token_request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.4/lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:18:in `get_access_token'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/linkedin-0.2.2/lib/linked_in/authorization_helpers.rb:28:in `authorize_from_request'
from linked_in.rb:17
```

Is my code missing something? What additional authorization is required?

According to the OAuth documentation:

> additional_authorization_required: The
>   access token does not have the correct
>   access scopes.

Still I don't understand why the access token does not have the correct access scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you strip trailing whitespace from your pin before using it

```
puts "Access this URL get the PIN and paste it here:"
pin = gets.strip

puts client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)
```

Comment: How could I miss that! Thanks allot ;)

Comment: No worries - I actually had the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to set the proper scope when configuring the Omniauth gem initializer besides how the App is already configured in the Linkedin Developer Network.

Try adding something like

```
:scope => 'r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress r_network'
```

to the existing config line you might have in the Omniauth (or Devise) initializer file.

```
provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
```